# A Riley: A Jewish landmark

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

My prefix is a verb, asking for something badly,

My infix is from Rome, we still use it today,

My suffix is a drink of courage, or so some say,

My whole is, all together, a Jew showing you how to start.

Comment: oh my gosh the grammar im in agony (yeah ill fix it thanks!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*My prefix is a verb, asking for something badly,*

> **beg** means to ask for something badly

*My infix is from Rome, we still use it today,*

> **egi** is Latin for 'I did'. Or maybe this refers to the word **ego**, a word we still use today, although its plural would be 'nos' rather than 'egi'. OP notes that this really clues **e.g.** an abbreviation for Latin 'exempli gratia' that we still use.

*My suffix is a drink of courage, or so some say,*

> **gin** is an alcoholic beverage that can grant people courage

My whole is, all together, a Jew showing you how to start.

> **[Begin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benny_Begin)** is a Jewish politician showing you how to **begin**

Comment: That was FAST! Wow. But I was planning on the infix being e.g., but that's amazing! Checkmark for you, with a side of upvotes.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. I'll edit it in.